# How i can do if flash is not configure then on auto capture image there should be some error message

Tags: javascript, flash

I'have tried too many libraries to check if flash is not configure then on auto capture image there should be some error message,you can share me library or source code how i can do this 
Thank YOu

Comment: Show your code for putting SWF into HTML page. Also you mean for a web-cam app? Flash does not "auto capture image" (user must first okay the web camera access). If there is no Flash you can detect and show other image or message text (choose correct answer posted below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below snippet will show the image if flash is not available.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" style="height: 80%; width: 80%;" data="mymovie.swf" >
   <param name="movie" value="mymovie.swf" >
   <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" >
   <param name="wmode" value="transparent" >
   <div>
      <img src="myimage.jpg" alt="original image" title="">
   </div>
</object>
```

This line :

```
<img src="myimage.jpg" alt="original image" title="">
```

Is for displaying some image if Flash is not available. Image could be designed to say "*You need Flash to use this*". Also instead of image, you can replace that with your error text.